# What happens when you type input()=='True'

Tags: python-3.x

```
young = (input() == 'True')
famous = (input() == 'True')

if young=='True' and famous=='True':
    print('You must be rich!')
else:
    print('There is always the lottery...')
```

Why does the above code gives False for True and True?

Comment: You convert to boolean so you should compare boolean: `if young==True and famous==True:`

Comment: `input()` blocks and waits for new-line delimited input from the standard input stream. Then it returns that values. Then `==` compares that to the string `'True'`... String comparisons return `bool` objects.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you...but what does this line do: (input() == 'True') , does it convert the input to bool?

Comment: Yes. The result of the `==` operator is a boolean value (`True` or `False`). You assign that result to `young` and `famous` making them boolean values.

Comment: It compares the input to a string 'True' and if input is equal to 'True', it stores `bool` `True` to `young`, and it input is not string 'True', it stores `bool` `False` to `young`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of `young = (input() == 'True')` is `bool`-type `True` or `False`, not a `str`-type:

```
>>> young = (input() == 'True')
True                               << user input text
>>> young
True
>>> type(young)
<class 'bool'>
>>> if young: print('young')
...
young
```

Anything except typing `True` will not compare equal to the string `'True'` and will result in `bool`-type `False`.

Comparing `bool`-type `True` to `str`-type `'True'` is always false.  Just check the booleans directly:

```
if young and famous:
    ...
```